# Grouping by a given number of row values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-8.4, greenplum

I have a list of values in a column 1, now I want to get the sum of next 5 row values or 6 row values like below and populate the value in appropriate column.

[image]

for example if you see 1st row value of the column 'next-5row-value' would be the sum of values from the current row to the next 5 rows which would be 9 and the next column would be sum of next 5 row values from that reference point.

I am trying to write functions to loop through to arrive at the sum. Is there an efficient way . can some one help me out. I am using postgres, greenplum . Thanks!

Comment: Tables are inherently unordered.  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering (say an auto-incremented id or creation date/time)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  yes I have weekend dates to refer to . now it turns up to the question  . Value of next five weeks from a given reference point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example if you have this simple table:

```
sebpa=# \d numbers
                         Table "public.numbers"
 Column |  Type   |                      Modifiers
--------+---------+------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer | not null default nextval('numbers_id_seq'::regclass)
 i      | integer |

sebpa=# select * from numbers limit 15;
  id  | i
------+---
 3001 | 3
 3002 | 0
 3003 | 5
 3004 | 1
 3005 | 1
 3006 | 4
 3007 | 1
 3008 | 1
 3009 | 4
 3010 | 0
 3011 | 4
 3012 | 0
 3013 | 3
 3014 | 2
 3015 | 1
(15 rows)
```

you can use this sql:

```
sebpa=# select id, i, sum(i) over( order by id rows between 0 preceding and 4 following) from numbers;
  id  | i | sum
------+---+-----
 3001 | 3 |  10
 3002 | 0 |  11
 3003 | 5 |  12
 3004 | 1 |   8
 3005 | 1 |  11
 3006 | 4 |  10
 3007 | 1 |  10
 3008 | 1 |   9
 3009 | 4 |  11
 3010 | 0 |   9
 3011 | 4 |  10
 3012 | 0 |  10
 3013 | 3 |  13
 3014 | 2 |  15
 3015 | 1 |  17
 3016 | 4 |  20
 3017 | 3 |  17
--cutted output
```

Comment: what if there are no 5 following a particular entry ? is there a way to replace those entries with null or 0 in the column next-5row-value ?

Comment: You need to add a CASE WHEN COUNT(*) over (order by id rows between current row and 4 following) = 5 then sum(i) over (order by id rows between current row and 4 following) END

Comment: of course postgresql 8.4 supports window functions http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand your question about replacing entries, of course @dnoeth has given right answer :)  look here http://pastebin.com/03c6rN3n

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT V,
       SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderingField
                       ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING) AS next_5row_value,
       SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderingField
                       ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 6 FOLLOWING) AS next_6row_value
FROM YourTable;
```

If you don't want NULLs in your "next_5row_value" column (the same for the 6row), you can use the COALESCE function (supported in PostgreSQL too) that returns the first not null expression.
Something like this:

```
SELECT V,
       COALESCE(SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderingField
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 5 FOLLOWING), 0) AS next_5row_value,
       COALESCE(SUM(V) OVER(ORDER BY YourOrderingField
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 6 FOLLOWING), 0) AS next_6row_value
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: @Corrado what if there are no 5 following a particular entry ? is there a way to replace those entries with null or 0 in the column next-5row-value ?

Comment: When you get NULL, then you want 0? Right?

Comment: I upgraded my answer to avoid NULLs in both columns. But I don't know if this is your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Postgres 8.4 supports the full functionality of window frames.  You can do this by using `lead()`:

```
select value,
       (value +
        lead(value, 1) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 2) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 3) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 4) over (order by id)
       ) as next5,
       (value +
        lead(value, 1) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 2) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 3) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 4) over (order by id) +
        lead(value, 5) over (order by id)
       ) as next5
from table t;
```

Using a window frame definition is definitely a better approach if the database supports it.  But the above will also work.

Comment: what if there are no 5 following a particular entry ? is there a way to replace those entries with null or 0 in the column next-5row-value ?

Comment: @user2569524 . . . This handles that situation automatically.  The `lead()` will return `NULL`, which will cause the entire sum to be `NULL`.

Comment: but say i have to consider 52 values below a certain reference point, in this approach i need to write these entries 52 times . is there an approach to handle this . or do we just put this in a loop inside a function ?

Comment: @user2569524 . . . Does your database support the approach using window frames?  If not, I can give you the solution.